# Finding the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\;\frac{f(x)}{\sin x}$ if $f(0) = 0$, $f'(0) = k > 0$ and $0 < f''(x) < f(x)$ for $x \in (0, \pi)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

> $f(x)$  satisfies the  conditions $1,2,3$:
>
> 1. $f(0)=0$
> 2. $f'(0)=k>0$
> 3. $0<x<\pi$ $\Rightarrow$ $0\leq f''(x)\leq f(x)$
>
> Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\;\dfrac{f(x)}{\sin x}$

Comment: k is a constant you say?

Comment: if it is so, $f''(x) =0 $; and so 3rd condition is redundant.

Answer (score 4):

You can find limit by using L'Hospital's rule
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {f(x)}{\sin x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac {f'(x)}{\cos x} = f'(0) = k
$$

Comment: What about the third condition for $f$?

Comment: It isn't necessary to find limit itself. Probably there are more things to find that OP didn't put in his post.